# Where do I install the Pico CMS files?

Tags: php, apache, content-management-system, picocms

The [install docs for PicoCMS](http://picocms.org/docs.html) say

1. First download and extract the latest version of Pico.
2. Upload the files to your server (via FTP or some other deployment).
3. That's it.  Tweak the .htaccess file if required.

For step 2, into **which folder** do I upload/copy the files?  There's several choices for us novices!  On my Windows/XAMPP setup, copying the files into the root xampp folder (the one that has apache, cgi-bin, php etc.) was a disaster.

I'll need answers for a Windows/XAMPP setup, plus for a "typical" shared host web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually wherever you want.

Pico is your whole project, so once you download it rename the `Pico-master` folder into the name you need your webapp/site to be, than start editing.

I use MAMP (Mac OSX) and I usually work this way:

```
- Localhost
  - ProjectName1
    - Folders        
  - ProjectName2
  - ProjectName3
```

Perhaps the best way for Pico is to do this:

```
- www (localhost folder name)
  - myProject
    - content
    - lib
    - plugins
    - themes
    - vendor
  - anotherProject
  - etc...
```

The point is that your content of the site is in the `content` folder and you don't want to move it from there otherwise you are to reconfigure Pico.

Than your site will be at `http://localhost/myProject`

Comment: Thanks - that worked for me.  Now, if I want Pico at the root, is that possible?  i.e., can you install it under www, so the URL will be http://localhost?  (Or, on a remote server, http://mydomainname.com)?

Comment: Sure you can. And actually for a website is exactly what you want to do.